# Prove that Matrix Norm (1 norm) and Vector Norm (1 norm) are Compatible

Tags: matrices, inequality, numerical-methods, vectors, normed-spaces

I need to show that, the  matrix norm ||A||1 and the vector norm ||v||1 are compatible, that is,

||Av||1 ≤ ||A||1 ||v||1 ,∀v∈Cn ∀A∈Cnxn

I have encountered this, but I don't understand what the writing underlined in red means:
[image]

Might help:
[image]

Comment: What have you tried? Follows directly from definition of matrix norm.

Comment: From what I've read, the definition of matrix norm refers to the relations between two matrices or a matrix and a scalar, but I have not seen a specific law regarding a matrix and a vector. Correct me if I am wrong or have missed something. I looked at the definition of norm 1 of Matrix and norm 1 of vector, and I know that the norm 1 of Av is actually norm 1 of a vector, because Av results in a vector.

Comment: You're begging, so I do: You are wrong. 
Clear question: What is the definition of matrix norm induced by a vector norm? This is nothing you have to "refer[s] to" or you "have not seen". Google it, check it, write it down.

Answer (score 0):

For a induced matrix norm it holds by definition: $$||A|| := \sup_{x\not= 0} \frac{||Ax||}{||x||}$$

Hence it follows for all $x\not= 0$:

$$\frac{||Ax||}{||x||} \le \sup_{x\not= 0} \frac{||Ax||}{||x||} =: ||A||$$

Multiplying both sides with $||x||$ gives the wanted result for $x\not=0$:
$$||Ax|| \le ||A||\cdot||x||$$

The relation also holds obviously for $x=0$ hence for all $x$.